# Track changes to a drupal entity

Tags: mysql, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I have a table similar to the following

```
$schema['mytable'] = array(
    'fields' => array(
        'id' => array(
            'type'=>'int',
            'not null' => TRUE
        ),
        'content' => array(
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'length' => 400
        )
    ),
    'primary key' => array('id')
);
```

defined in hook_schema. I have a JavaScript client application that repeatedly pulls the contents of this table to the client so that it updates near instantly when the table is modified (like a shared spreadsheet in google docs).  What I want to do is optimise it to only provide changed records each time. My initial thought was to give each element a timestamp property and to have the client keep track of the highest timestamp it has seen, then request everything with a newer timestamp.  Then I saw on the Drupal api documentation for [hook_schema](http://api.drupal.org/hook_schema) that there appears to be a magic property of all nodes called changed.  Can I get a similar magic property for my entities, and would this help in my scenario, or would I be better off just rolling my own logic to do this.  Performance is fairly critical as this will likely be the key bottleneck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are mistaken about the "magic property" 'changed', as there is nothing magic about it. It is just a normal int field in the node table that gets populated with a UNIX timestamp, pretty much like the one you are proposing for your use case.

The misinterpretation probably stems from the `hook_schema` API documentation only showing a part of the node table definition, as noted inline in the code:

```
function hook_schema() {
  $schema['node'] = array(
    // example (partial) specification for table "node"
[...]
```

If you look at the full implementation of [`node_schema()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.install/function/node_schema/7), you'll find the following definition for the 'changed' field:

```
[...]
'changed' => array(
  'description' => 'The Unix timestamp when the node was most recently saved.', 
  'type' => 'int', 
  'not null' => TRUE, 
  'default' => 0,
),
[...]
```

So no magic here, and you should probably just go ahead with your own logic as planned :)

Comment: Thanks, I'd missed that comment about the specification only being partial.